# Comparing + inserting into lists of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to compare two lists of strings, which are textSplitted and column1.

Currently i am looping through both lists and if they **are not the same**, column2 and column3 should get a hyphen (-) in them. If they **are the same**, then values of column2 and column3 should remain on that position.

note1: column1, column2, column3 initially have the same length.

note2: column1 will never contain elements which textSplitted does not have.

```
textSplitted = ['wow','this','is','some','nice','text']
column1 = ['this','is','some','text']
column2 = ['A','B','C','D']
column3 = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4',]

i = 0
j = 0

for item in textSplitted:
    if textSplitted[i] == column1[j]:
        i+=1
        j+=1
    elif textSplitted[i] != column1[j]:
        column2.insert(j,"-")
        column3.insert(j,"-")
        i+=1

print(textSplitted)
print(column2)
print(column3)
```

This yields output:

```
['wow', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'nice', 'text']
['-', 'A', 'B', '-', 'C', 'D']
['-', 'Q1', 'Q2', '-', 'Q3', 'Q4']
```

But I want to achieve:

```
['wow', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'nice', 'text']
['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-', 'D']
['-', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', '-', 'Q4']
```

**Note:** if I would add an extra element to textSplitted, output yields: *list index out of range error*. But, if column1 is 'out of' comparisons, then the leftover elements in textSplitted should get a corresponding hyphen (-) in column2 and column3. E.g.:

```
['wow', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'nice', 'text','yes','indeed']
['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-', 'D','-','-']
['-', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', '-', 'Q4','-','-']
```

Comment: I'm curious as to what the output should be if your two lists were the following: 
`textSplitted = ['wow','is','some','nice','text']
column1 = ['this','is','some','text']`
My concern here is that this is an alignment problem that is more complex than any of the answers are giving it credit for. (all of the answers so far will likely return something like:
`['-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']` 
Is this the desired output?

Comment: Since this piece of coding is part of a bigger project, i can tell for sure that it would never be the case that column1 has an element which textSplitted doesn't have. Thanks for you concern though :)

Comment: I would recommend editing the original post to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
textSplitted = ['wow','this','is','some','nice','text','yes','indeed']
column1 = ['this','is','some','text']
column2 = ['A','B','C','D']
column3 = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4',]

i = 0
j = 0

while j < len(column1):
    if textSplitted[i] == column1[j]:
        i+=1
        j+=1
    elif textSplitted[i] != column1[j]:
        column2.insert(i,"-")
        column3.insert(i,"-")
        i+=1

while i< len(textSplitted):
    column2.append("-")
    column3.append("-")
    i+=1

print(textSplitted)
print(column2)
print(column3)
```

Prints:

```
['wow', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'nice', 'text', 'yes', 'indeed']
['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-', 'D', '-', '-']
['-', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', '-', 'Q4', '-', '-']
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i need!

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not be a requirement, but the posted solutions (when I veiwed them, maybe they were updated now) will fail if an element from column1 appears more than once in textSplitted, for example:

```
textSplitted = ['wow','this','is','some','nice','text','yes','indeed','it','is']
column1 = ['this','is','some','text']

output will be:

['wow', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'nice', 'text', 'yes', 'indeed', 'it', 'is']
['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-', 'D', '-', '-', '-', '-']
['-', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', '-', 'Q4', '-', '-', '-', '-']

failing to pick up the repeated 'is'.
```

Below fixes that potential issue:

```
textSplitted = ['wow','this','is','some','nice','text','yes','indeed','it','is']
column1 = ['this','is','some','text']
column2 = ['A','B','C','D']
column3 = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4',]

a = list(map(lambda w: w if w in column1 else '-', textSplitted))
column2 = list(map(lambda w: w if w=='-' else column2[column1.index(w)], a))
column3 = list(map(lambda w: w if w=='-' else column3[column1.index(w)], a))

print(textSplitted)
print(column2)
print(column3)

['wow', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'nice', 'text', 'yes', 'indeed', 'it', 'is']
['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-', 'D', '-', '-', '-', 'B']
['-', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', '-', 'Q4', '-', '-', '-', 'Q2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more simple:

```
j = 0
for i, word in enumerate(textSplitted):
    if i >= len(column1):
        break
    if word != column1[i-j]:
        column2.insert(i, '-')
        column3.insert(i, '-')
        j+= 1
```

Comment: `IndexError: list index out of range` when adding more elements to textSplitted

Answer (score 0):

You have to do replacement at index x.

```
textSplitted = ['wow','this','is','some','nice','text']
column1 = ['this','is','some','text']
column2 = ['A','B','C','D']
column3 = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4',]

i = 0
j = 0

for i in range(0, len(textSplitted)):
    print i,textSplitted[i], j,column1[j]
    if textSplitted[i] != column1[j]:
        column2.insert(i,"-")
        column3.insert(i,"-")
    else:
        j = j+1


print(textSplitted)
print(column2)
print(column3)
```

Comment: I would also like to be able to add elements to textSplitted without getting `IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 0):

I am rather using the mapping approach in such cases. So here is somehow a different solution with following advantages:

- you can easily reuse the mapper for potential new columns
- it properly handles the repetitive occurrences of words
- column1 can have words which are not in textSplitted (they result in '-')

code:

```
textSplitted = ['wow', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'nice', 'text','yes','indeed']
column1 = ['this','is','some','text']
column2 = ['A','B','C','D']
column3 = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4',]

last_i = 0
mapper = []
for w in textSplitted:
    try:
        new_i = column1.index(w, last_i)
    except ValueError:
        mapper.append("-")
    else:
        mapper.append(new_i)
        last_i = new_i+1

# mapper = ["-", 0, 1, 2, "-", 3, "-", "-"]

print (textSplitted)
print ([column2[i] if i is not "-" else "-" for i in mapper])
print ([column3[i] if i is not "-" else "-" for i in mapper])

>>> 
['wow', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'nice', 'text', 'yes', 'indeed']
['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-', 'D', '-', '-']
['-', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', '-', 'Q4', '-', '-']
```

You can try with the repetitive occurrences - avoiding the second "text":

```
textSplitted = ['wow', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'nice', 'text','yes','indeed', 'text']
column1 = ['this','is','some','text']
column2 = ['A','B','C','D']
column3 = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4',]
...
>>>
['wow', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'nice', 'text', 'yes', 'indeed', 'text']
['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-', 'D', '-', '-', '-']
['-', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', '-', 'Q4', '-', '-', '-']
```

or even mapping the second "text" to the right outcome:

```
textSplitted = ['wow', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'nice', 'text','yes','indeed', 'text']
column1 = ['this','is','some','text', 'text']
column2 = ['A','B','C','D', 'E']
column3 = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q5']
...

>>>
['wow', 'this', 'is', 'some', 'nice', 'text', 'yes', 'indeed', 'text']
['-', 'A', 'B', 'C', '-', 'D', '-', '-', 'E']
['-', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', '-', 'Q4', '-', '-', 'Q5']
```